# OAuth: авторизация вконтакте и получение токена для использования API

Tags: java, oauth

Здравствуйте. Решил реализовать приложение для парсинга некой информации пользователей вк. Первый пункт из [мануала](http://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) сделан, но я столкнулся с огромной проблемой: если пользователь не авторизован, то появляется форма авторизации (в браузере, который я не использую в моем приложении), через которую он должен пройти дабы разрешить права доступа к его странице моему приложению. 
Нагуглил кучу старых примеров, в которых используется хэдер "location" getFirstHeader("location").getValue(); После отсылки POST запроса я получаю ответ от сервера, в котором есть 10 хэдеров, но нету "location". Как я понимаю, разработчики его убрали. Без него я не могу сформировать запрос авторизации пользователя, в этом вся и проблема. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

class Login {

    String client_id = "5407630";
    String redirect_uri = "http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html";
    String display = "popup";
    String scope = "messages";
    String response_type = "token";
    String v = "5.50";

    String http = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=" + client_id +
            "&display=" + display +
            "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri +
            "&scope=" + scope +
            "&response_type=" + response_type +
            "&v=" + v;

    Login() throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(http);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        String s = response.getStatusLine().toString();
          System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы вам не воспользоваться годовой и написанной за вас [VK SDK](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk) для 
анроид?
Будет намного проще.

```
VKSdk.login(Activity runningActivity, String... scope);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался 
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию) 
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хочу сделать все стандартными методами, без готовых решений.